# VBA: click on next button on a website (loop)

Tags: vba, loops, web, button, click

I'm trying to get info from a website with many pages. I already got the extraction of the information, however I can't perform a loop to click the "next page" button and do it again..

Can you please help me?

Thanks,
M

```
Sub website_test()

Dim ie As Object
Dim ht As HTMLDocument
Dim button As Object
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 100

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate ("https://old.reddit.com/r/fashion/new/")

Do Until ie.readyState = 4
   DoEvents
Loop
    
Set ht = ie.document

Set elems = ht.getElementsByClassName("title may-blank")

For Each elem In elems
    Debug.Print (elem.innerText)
    Next

Set button = ht.getElementsByTagName("nofollow next")

button(i + 1).Click --> **is this where it gets an error (run-time error 91: object variable or width block variable not set)**

Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I mainly modified the way you get the 'next' button Element from DOM.

```
Sub website_test()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim ht As HTMLDocument
    Dim button As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To 5
    
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        
        ie.navigate ("https://old.reddit.com/r/fashion/new/")
        
        Do Until ie.readyState = 4
           DoEvents
        Loop
            
        Set ht = ie.document
        
        Set elems = ht.getElementsByClassName("title may-blank")
        
        For Each elem In elems
            Debug.Print (elem.innerText)
        Next
        Set button = ht.querySelector("[rel='nofollow next']")
        button.Click
        ie.Quit  
    Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it now works. However it is looping on the printing, and not on the clicking button. I need it to print the words in one page, them click next, them print the words in the new page, then click next ... how can I do this?

Comment: Can anyone help me?